# How to link two classes from two different python files

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm building a website for my school project using tkinter (specifically customtkinter).  What i want to achieve is that when I click the manager button on the main window, the manager window to open up. The main window and manager window exist in two different python files. Unfortunately its been nothing but errors for the past 5 hours for me.

Below is the code for the main window

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox,ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import Py_SQL_conn as PS
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter
from customtkinter import *
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import trailtk19 as tr

#try to increase window size...
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"


import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font as tkfont # python 3

class SampleApp(customtkinter.CTk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        customtkinter.CTk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        
        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = CTkFrame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage,Booking_page,Ava_Sch_page,Passenger_page):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class Booking_page(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        main_frame=CTkFrame(master=self)
        main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        but1=CTkButton(master=main_frame,width=190,text="Main",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        but1.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)
        but2=CTkButton(master=main_frame,width=190,text="See sch",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Ava_Sch_page"))
        but2.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)


class Ava_Sch_page(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        frame1 = CTkFrame(master=self)
        frame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        
        my_canvas = Canvas(frame1)
        my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        ctk_textbox_scrollbar = customtkinter.CTkScrollbar(frame1, command=my_canvas.yview)
        ctk_textbox_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=ctk_textbox_scrollbar.set)
        my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))
        
        main_frame=CTkFrame(my_canvas,width=1300,height=2000+1000,fg_color="white")
        main_frame.pack()
        my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=main_frame, anchor="nw")
        header=CTkFrame(main_frame,width=1300,height=55,corner_radius=0,fg_color="#57a1f8")
        header.place(x=0,y=0)

        man_lab=CTkLabel(header,text="Welcome Manager",bg='white',text_font=('Microsoft YaHei UI Light',23))
        man_lab.place(x=10,y=6)

        #Navigation bar
        nav_frame=CTkFrame(main_frame,width=925,corner_radius=0,fg_color="#1f6aa5",height=35)
        nav_frame.place(x=0,y=55)
        
        but1=CTkButton(nav_frame,text="Bookings",fg_color="#144870",corner_radius=0,height=35,width=90,state=DISABLED,command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Book_det"))
        but1.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)

        but2=CTkButton(nav_frame,text="Passengers",corner_radius=0,height=35,width=100,state=DISABLED,command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Pass_det"))
        but2.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)

        but3=CTkButton(nav_frame,text='',corner_radius=0,height=35,width=1000,state=DISABLED)
        but3.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0,fill=BOTH)

        path = "aurora.jpeg"
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
        Label(master=main_frame,image=self.img,height=650,width=510).place(x=500,y=50)
        customtkinter.CTkButton(master=main_frame,width=190,text="Booking",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Booking_page")).place(x=1000,y=150)
        customtkinter.CTkButton(master=main_frame,width=190,text="details",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Passenger_page")).place(x=1000,y=1950)
            

class Passenger_page(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        main_frame=CTkFrame(master=self)
        main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        customtkinter.CTkButton(master=main_frame,width=190,text="Avail",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Ava_Sch_page")).pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)
        customtkinter.CTkButton(master=main_frame,width=190,text="Main",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage")).pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)



        
class StartPage(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        def confirm():
            global na
            u=user.get()
            p=passw.get()
            datsum=PS.connectorconn("Select * from managers;")
            for x in datsum:
                if (u==x[3]) and (p==x[4]):
                    con="yes"
                    break
                else:
                    con="yes"

            if con=="yes":
                controller.show_frame("Booking_page")

        #Website opens into booking page

        frame1 = CTkFrame(master=self)
        frame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # Create A Canvas
        my_canvas = Canvas(frame1)
        my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # Add A Scrollbar To The Canvas
        ctk_textbox_scrollbar = customtkinter.CTkScrollbar(frame1, command=my_canvas.yview)
        ctk_textbox_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        ##my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
        ##my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        # Configure The Canvas
        my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=ctk_textbox_scrollbar.set)
        my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

        # Create ANOTHER Frame INSIDE the Canvas
        
        main_frame=CTkFrame(my_canvas,width=1300,height=2000)
        main_frame.pack()
        # Add that New frame To a Window In The Canvas
        my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=main_frame, anchor="nw")

        #Code for scroll bar ends here. To use again, copy paste the above code and when adding widgets to the frame, make sure to put master=mainframe.
        #NOTE: Only use place geometry manager to add subsequent widgets.



        header=CTkFrame(main_frame,width=1300,height=55,corner_radius=0,fg_color="#57a1f8")
        header.place(x=0,y=55)

        man_lab=CTkLabel(header,text="  ",bg='white',text_font=('Microsoft YaHei UI Light',23))
        man_lab.place(x=10,y=6)

        #Navigation bar
        nav_frame=CTkFrame(main_frame,width=925,corner_radius=0,fg_color="#1f6aa5",height=35)
        nav_frame.place(x=0,y=108)

        but=CTkButton(nav_frame,text="Schedule",corner_radius=0,height=35,state=DISABLED,command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Pass_det"))
        but.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)
        
        but1=CTkButton(nav_frame,text="Book flight",fg_color="#144870",corner_radius=0,height=35,state=DISABLED,command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Book_det"))
        but1.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)

        but2=CTkButton(nav_frame,text="View ticket",corner_radius=0,height=35,state=DISABLED,command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Booking_page"))
        but2.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)

        but3=CTkButton(nav_frame,text="Cancel ticket",corner_radius=0,height=35,state=DISABLED,command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Booking_page"))
        but3.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)

        but4=CTkButton(nav_frame,text="About us",corner_radius=0,height=35,state=DISABLED,command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Booking_page"))
        but4.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)

        def y():
            tr.Display()

        but5=CTkButton(nav_frame,text="Manager Log",corner_radius=0,height=35,command=lambda: y)
        but5.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)

        but6=CTkButton(nav_frame,text='',corner_radius=0,height=35,width=1000,state=DISABLED)
        but6.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0,fill=BOTH)

root=SampleApp()
root.title("Main_window")
root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
root.resizable(False,False)
root.configure(bg="white")
def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        root.destroy()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop()
```

And below is the manger window

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox,ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import Py_SQL_conn as PS
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter
from customtkinter import *

#try to increase window size...
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"


import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font as tkfont # python 3

class SampleApp(customtkinter.CTk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        customtkinter.CTk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        
        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = CTkFrame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage,Book_det,Pass_det):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

        
class StartPage(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        def confirm():
            global na
            u=user.get()
            p=passw.get()
            datsum=PS.connectorconn("Select * from managers;")
            #error if not in datsum and then the stuff i guess....good prgress
            for x in datsum:
                if (u==x[3]) and (p==x[4]):
                    con="yes"
                    break
                else:
                    con="no"

            if con=="yes":
                controller.show_frame("Book_det")
            else:
                messagebox.showwarning("Warning","Invalid Credentials.")

            




        main_frame=CTkFrame(master=self)
        main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


        path = "aurora.jpeg"
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
        Label(master=main_frame,image=self.img,height=650,width=510).place(x=85,y=50)



        frame=CTkFrame(master=main_frame,width=350,height=350,bg="white")
        frame.place(x=480,y=83)

        heading=CTkLabel(master=frame,text="Manager Login",fg="#57a1f8",bg='white',text_font=('Microsoft YaHei UI Light',23))
        heading.place(x=61,y=25)
 

        #username             
        user= CTkEntry(master=frame,width=290,placeholder_text="Username", border=0,bg='white',text_font=('Microsoft YaHei UI Light',11))
        user.place(x=30,y=120)
        ##user.bind('<FocusIn>',on_enter)
        ##user.bind('<FocusOut>',on_leave)
        ##CTkFrame(master=frame,width=295,bg='black').place(x=25,y=107)


        #Password
        passw= customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame,width=290,placeholder_text="Password",bg='white',border=0,text_font=('Microsoft YaHei UI Light',11))
        passw.place(x=30,y=180)
        ##passw.bind('<FocusIn>',on_enter)
        ##passw.bind('<FocusOut>',on_leave)
        ##CTkFrame(master=frame,width=295,bg='black').place(x=25,y=177)

        #Submit button
        customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame,width=190,text="Log in",command=lambda: confirm()).place(x=80,y=270)

class Book_det(CTkFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        #For every frame...
        self.controller = controller
        main_frame1=CTkFrame(master=self)
        main_frame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        header=CTkFrame(main_frame1,width=925,height=55,corner_radius=0,fg_color="#57a1f8")
        header.pack()

        man_lab=CTkLabel(header,text="Welcome Manager",bg='white',text_font=('Microsoft YaHei UI Light',23))
        man_lab.place(x=10,y=6)


        nav_frame=CTkFrame(main_frame1,width=925,corner_radius=0,fg_color="#1f6aa5",height=35)
        nav_frame.pack(anchor="w",fill=BOTH)
        
        but1=CTkButton(nav_frame,text="Bookings",fg_color="#144870",corner_radius=0,height=35,width=90,command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Book_det"))
        but1.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)

        but2=CTkButton(nav_frame,text="Passengers",corner_radius=0,height=35,width=100,command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Pass_det"))
        but2.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)

        but3=CTkButton(nav_frame,text='',corner_radius=0,height=35,width=1000,state=DISABLED)
        but3.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0,fill=BOTH)

        

        
        

        fs_frame = CTkFrame(main_frame1)
        fs_frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1,pady=25,padx=25)
       # fs_frame.pack()

        reg_dep = ttk.Treeview(fs_frame,height=18)

        reg_dep['columns'] = ('BookingID', 'Dep_Des_Code', 'Arr_Des_Code', 'Passenger_ID','Departure_Date','Return_Date','Booked_Seat')

        reg_dep.column("#0", width=0,  stretch=NO)
        reg_dep.column('BookingID',anchor=CENTER, width=120)
        reg_dep.column('Dep_Des_Code',anchor=CENTER, width=140)
        reg_dep.column('Arr_Des_Code',anchor=CENTER,width=140)
        reg_dep.column('Passenger_ID',anchor=CENTER,width=140)
        reg_dep.column('Departure_Date',anchor=CENTER,width=160)
        reg_dep.column('Return_Date',anchor=CENTER,width=160)
        reg_dep.column('Booked_Seat',anchor=CENTER,width=140)

        reg_dep.heading("#0",text="",anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('BookingID',text='BookingID',anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('Dep_Des_Code',text='Dep_Des_Code',anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('Arr_Des_Code',text='Arr_Des_Code',anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('Passenger_ID',text='Passenger_ID',anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('Departure_Date',text='Departure_Date',anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('Return_Date',text='Return_Date',anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('Booked_Seat',text='Booked_Seat',anchor=CENTER)


        import mysql.connector as mycon
        conn=mycon.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="12345678",database="aurora_airlines")
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("Select * from bookings;")
        data=cursor.fetchall()
        Records=[]
        for row in data:
                Records.append(row)
        count=cursor.rowcount
        for iid in range(count):
            reg_dep.insert(parent='',index='end',iid=iid,text='',
            values=(Records[iid][0],Records[iid][1],Records[iid][2],Records[iid][3], Records[iid][4],Records[iid][5],Records[iid][6]))  
        reg_dep.pack(pady=85)

##        button = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_frame1,corner_radius=0,height=10,text="Go to the start page",
##                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
##        button.grid(row=0,column=0)
##        button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_frame1, text="go to page two",
##                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
##        button1.grid(row=0,column=1)


class Pass_det(CTkFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        #For every frame...
        self.controller = controller
        main_frame1=CTkFrame(master=self)
        main_frame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        header=CTkFrame(main_frame1,width=925,height=55,corner_radius=0,fg_color="#57a1f8")
        header.pack()

        man_lab=CTkLabel(header,text="Welcome Manager",bg='white',text_font=('Microsoft YaHei UI Light',23))
        man_lab.place(x=10,y=6)

        nav_frame=CTkFrame(main_frame1,height=37,width=925,corner_radius=0,fg_color="#1f6aa5")
        nav_frame.pack(anchor="w",fill=BOTH,padx=0,pady=0)
        
        but1=CTkButton(nav_frame,text="Bookings",corner_radius=0,height=35,width=90,command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Book_det"))
        but1.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)

        but2=CTkButton(nav_frame,text="Passengers",fg_color="#144870",corner_radius=0,height=35,width=100,command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Pass_det"))
        but2.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0)

        but3=CTkButton(nav_frame,text='',corner_radius=0,height=35,width=1000,state=DISABLED)
        but3.pack(side=LEFT,pady=0,padx=0,fill=BOTH)

        
        

        fs_frame = CTkFrame(main_frame1)
        fs_frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1,pady=25,padx=25)
       # fs_frame.pack()

        reg_dep = ttk.Treeview(fs_frame,height=22)
        CTkLabel(fs_frame,text="").pack()
        reg_dep['columns'] = ('Passenger_ID', 'First_Name', 'Last_Name',
                              'Passport_ID', 'Meal_Preference','Phone_number',
                              'Email', 'Class')

        reg_dep.column("#0", width=0,  stretch=NO)
        reg_dep.column('Passenger_ID',anchor=CENTER, width=120)
        reg_dep.column('First_Name',anchor=CENTER, width=140)
        reg_dep.column('Last_Name',anchor=CENTER,width=140)
        reg_dep.column('Passport_ID',anchor=CENTER,width=140)
        reg_dep.column('Meal_Preference',anchor=CENTER,width=160)
        reg_dep.column('Phone_number',anchor=CENTER,width=160)
        reg_dep.column('Email',anchor=CENTER,width=140)
        reg_dep.column('Class',anchor=CENTER,width=160)

        reg_dep.heading("#0",text="",anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('Passenger_ID',text='Passenger_ID',anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('First_Name',text='First_Name',anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('Last_Name',text='Last_Name',anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('Passport_ID',text='Passport_ID',anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('Meal_Preference',text='Meal_Preference',anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('Phone_number',text='Phone_number',anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('Email',text='Email',anchor=CENTER)
        reg_dep.heading('Class',text='Class',anchor=CENTER)


        import mysql.connector as mycon
        conn=mycon.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="12345678",database="aurora_airlines")
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("Select * from passengers;")
        data=cursor.fetchall()
        Records=[]
        for row in data:
                Records.append(row)
        count=cursor.rowcount
        for iid in range(count):
            reg_dep.insert(parent='',index='end',iid=iid,text='',
            values=(Records[iid][0],Records[iid][1],Records[iid][2],Records[iid][3], Records[iid][4],Records[iid][5],Records[iid][6],Records[iid][7]))  
        reg_dep.pack(pady=44)


def Display():
    root=SampleApp()
    root.title("Manager_Login")
    root.geometry('925x500+300+200')
    root.resizable(False,False)
    root.configure(bg="white")
    root.mainloop()
```

I keep getting the 'image "pyimage2" doesn't exist' error. Then when I used the call method, it kept opening another python window which I don't want. I also don't want to merge the above codes into one file since I have a lot of code to add for the other parts of the project.

I apologize for the messy code since these were just test files

I'm just a beginner in python so I might have made some mistakes I'm not aware of. I would be grateful if anyone could help me! Thank you!

Comment: What is filename of this manger window? How do u called manger window?

Comment: The manager window is called "Manager_Login"

Comment: When i try to link the the manager window to a button in the main window, an "pyimage2 does not exist" error occurs.  when the manager log button is pressed in the main window, the command tr.Display() should run the Display() function in the manger login window should work, but it doesn't work